# Find color temperature from spectral response

Tags: python, colors, dataset, light

I search for some Python library that can find color temperature from spectral response from spectrometer.
I have single spectrum output like this:

[image]

I want to find color temperate of my light source.

The outputs shuld be like here (values not plot):

[image]

I searched a lot but I didn't find anything, in libraries like colour-science or python-colormath I don't see option like that. Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly possible with [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour):

```py
>>> import colour
>>> D65 = colour.ILLUMINANTS_SDS['D65']
>>> XYZ = colour.sd_to_XYZ(D65)
>>> xy = colour.XYZ_to_xy(XYZ)
>>> colour.xy_to_CCT(xy)
6507.5108766555786
```

Or with the *Automatic Colour Conversion Graph*:

```py
>>> import colour
>>> colour.convert(D65, 'Spectral Distribution', 'CCT', sd_to_XYZ={'illuminant': colour.sd_ones()})
6507.5108766555786
```

You have to specify an illuminant here to override the default which happens to be D65 :)

Answer (score 2):

The process normally takes the following steps:

- Convert the spectrum to a CIE XYZ value
- Convert the XYZ value to RGB using a specific CIE color system
- Apply gamma correction

There is an explanation and code [here](https://scipython.com/blog/converting-a-spectrum-to-a-colour/).

**Update**

You may prefer to use this project: https://github.com/aerobio/spectra/

Comment: Yes I seen that. But I have got single spectrum. Not with RGB colours.

Comment: I have updated my answer pointing to a different project.